# Is it possible to stream into a TextBox or similar control object?

Tags: c#, stream

I currently have an export to xml function that streams to a new file.

What i want to be able to do is create a file preview box so that a user can decide if they want / need to export or not.

The files are on average around 200,000 lines so i cannot just += or stringbuild them together, im gonna need to stream the data into a control.

Is it possible to stream data from a database into a TextBox or similar text control?

Comment: at the end of the streaming process, do you want to display all 200k lines at once?   Or do you want to have the N most recently downloaded lines?

Comment: I would like to have a full preview of the file if it is possible im just not sure if it would be possible to display without taking up too much memory?

Comment: it does not make any sense to display that amount of data into a textbox or something like that. You said it's preview so just display part of it as a preview. Or make a special page so that you can display in small part of it in each time.

Answer (score 0):

What about streaming to a MemoryStream and then converting to string through Encoding?